# Show form based on variable string input

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to show a form like `Form_1.show` based on a string variable like with the worksheets or controls like such

```
Private Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        me.Controls("Label_" & i) = Rnd()
    Next i

    'Or select a worksheet based on an input

    With Me.ListBox1
        For i = 1 to 5
            .additem Cstr("Sheet" & i)
        Next i
    End With

    ThisWorkBook.Worksheets(me.ListBox1).Activate
End Sub
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is show Form1 to 10 based on a choice made from a listbox in a form and instead of writing a lot of `If` statements is it possible to change the form which is shown based on a choice?

Below is the current situation.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim Table1 as ListObject
    Set Table1 = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Listobjects("Forms_List")
    Dim Rows As Long
    Rows = Table1.ListRows.Count
    Dim i As Long

    With Me.ListBox1
        For i = 1 To Rows
            .AddItem Table1.DataBodyRange(i, 1)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_dblclick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean) 
    'This is what I want to avoid, mainly because it isn't flexible
    If Me.ListBox1 = "Form1" Then Form1.Show
    If Me.ListBox1 = "Form2" Then Form2.Show
    If Me.ListBox1 = "Form3" Then Form3.Show
    If Me.ListBox1 = "Form4" Then Form4.Show
    If Me.ListBox1 = "Form5" Then Form5.Show
    If Me.ListBox1 = "Form6" Then Form6.Show
    If Me.ListBox1 = "Form7" Then Form7.Show
    If Me.ListBox1 = "Form8" Then Form8.Show
    If Me.ListBox1 = "Form9" Then Form9.Show
    If Me.ListBox1 = "Form10" Then Form10.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried your example code? What happened? Also, if you want to avoid a bunch of IFs, there's always the SELECT CASE.

Comment: The example code is just to demonstrate what I want but with different objects, it doesn't even run because in the same sub a worksheet is activated based on a choice in a listbox that is filled in the same sub. Also I've looked at the select but that still is many lines of code for each different form I might want to show, it would be easiest, provided it is possible to have something like `Forms(me.listbox1).Show` but that obviously doesn't work and so far I've not been able to find out if even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this :

```
VBA.UserForms.Add(Me.ListBox1).Show
```

Source:
[How to Display a UserForm Whose Name Is in a Variable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/157609)

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I couldn't find that resource but thank you.

Comment: @SilentRevolution , you are welcome!, maybe  because it is very old (for Microsoft Excel 97)